# Connect directly to Kestrel behind IIS

Tags: c#, iis, kestrel-http-server

I have a web app made in C# using asp.net core 2.0.
This app is hosted in IIS, as this is the recommended way to expose it to the internet.

I am now making some services hosted in the same local lan as the webapp, which need to connect to the above webappp. I can connect to the public iis server which of course works. However, would it also be possible to directly connect to the Kestrel server managed by IIS? So instead of connecting to public_ip/somewhere, connect to kestrel-local-ip:port/somewhere. The advantages would be:

- avoid an extra hop
- the kestrel app is still hosted and managed by IIS, so no worrying about self-hosting/management.

Reading the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.1 it states: "Additional checks are performed, and requests that don't originate from the module are rejected.". Reading the Github repro, this seems to be an HTTP header called "MS-ASPNETCORE-TOKEN".

So is this scenario possible somehow? To connect directly to IIS but ALSO to kestrel directly?

If it is possible, should I do this? The performance gains seem immense as I have a lot of small requests which Kestrel can handle really well.

Comment: Stick to IIS and wait for .NET Core 2.2 to introduce the new integration mode to boost performance. The advantages you listed above are not worth the while to go a hacky way.

Comment: Are you referring to https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/5403 ?

Comment: Hi, any news about it? is it possibile to connect directly to Kestrel behind Iis?

Answer (score 0):

I have test this scenario。

when APP kestrel behind iis,

1. you can use netstat command  get the kestrel  process "port".
2. and then curl the "localhost:port" , you will get the 400 bad request， also you can get a error log indicate the MS-ASPNETCORE-TOKEN token .
3. you can curl the "localhost:port"again with the MS-ASPNETCORE-TOKEN request header.